# equivalence relation problem - checking

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

We define eqiuvalence relation $\equiv$ at set $P(\mathbb{Z})$ as follow:

$A \equiv B \iff |A \setminus \mathbb{N}| = |B \setminus\mathbb{N}|$

a)find equivalence class for $\emptyset$

b)find cardinality of quotient set $P(\mathbb{Z})$

c)find cardinality of equivalence classes

my attempt:

a) $[\emptyset]= \{B \in P(\mathbb{N}) \}$ since then $|B \setminus\mathbb{N}|= \emptyset$ (I don't know if the way I described this set is proper but the idea is such set contains only natural numbers)

b)if $A,B\in P(\mathbb{Z\setminus N})$ and $A \neq B$ then $A \not\equiv B$ and since $|P(\mathbb{Z\setminus N})|=|\mathbb{R}|$ then our set is continuum

c) if $A$ has only finite amount of negative integers say $k$ then $|[A]|=\aleph_0$ since we're picking $k$ negative integers from $\mathbb{Z}$ and finite union of countable is countable

if $A$ has infintely many negative integers then we have $|[A]|=\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ ( I have problem how to explain that but that's my intuition)

if $A$ has no negative integers then I think also $\aleph_1$ since at this equiv class will be $P(\mathbb{N})$ whose cardinality is $\aleph_1$

Comment: Did you mean $\aleph_1$ as *continuum*? You should rather use a $\mathrm c$-like letter for that, or $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: yes here $\aleph_1$ means continuum, btw why it's bad notation ?

Comment: Note that $|A\smallsetminus\mathbb N|=|B\smallsetminus\mathbb N|$ iff $|A\cap \mathbb Z^-)|= |B\cap\mathbb Z^{-}|$, where $\mathbb Z^-=\mathbb Z\smallsetminus\mathbb N$. Hence, $|A\cap\mathbb Z^{-}|$ determines class of $A$, hence you have $\aleph_0$ many classes. Note that for every $A\subseteq\mathbb Z^{-}$, $\{A\cup B\mid B\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\}\subseteq [A]$, hence every class is of cardinality $\mathfrak c$.

Comment: I don't get why every calss is continuum I mean why case when $A$ has finite amout of $\mathbb{Z}^{-1}$ is continuum?

Comment: @SMM: No, Mario is right, as $A$ can be any subset of $\Bbb Z^-$, there are continuum many equivalence classes.

Comment: @Mario: It is a bad notation because $\aleph_{n+1}$ usually denotes the *next* cardinal after $\aleph_n$, and it is proven that the continuum hypothesis ($\aleph_1=c$) is independent from the axiom system ZFC.

Comment: @Berci No. If $A,B\subseteq \mathbb Z^-$ and $|A|=|B|$, then $A\equiv B$. And $|A|$ can be $0,1,2,\ldots,\aleph_0$. Only this determines class.

Comment: @Mario Note that for $A\subseteq \mathbb Z^-$, $\{A\cup B\mid B\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\}\subseteq [A]\subseteq\mathcal P(\mathbb Z)$ implies $\mathfrak c\leq |[A]|\leq\mathfrak c$, hence $|[A]|=\mathfrak c$.

Comment: @SMM: Ahh.. you are right. I forgot to take the absolute value sign into account..

Comment: ok thanks for help !